# XmlElement Attribute order is not saved

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xml-serialization

I wrote the following code in my class and expected that the order will remain.
but in the dll the order is not saved, is there any way to save the order?

my code:

```
[XmlElement(Type = typeof(ConfigItem))]
[XmlElement(ElementName = "Item")]
public List<ConfigItem> Items
{
    get { return subItems_; }
    set { subItems_ = value; }
}
```

Dll property header from ILSpy:

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "Item"), XmlElement(Type = typeof(ConfigItem))]
public List<ConfigItem> Items
{
    get
    {
        return this.subItems_;
    }
    set
    {
        this.subItems_ = value;
    }
}
```

the order is important because the output xml is different, in case of

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "Item"), XmlElement(Type = typeof(ConfigItem))]
```

the xml looks like that:

```
<ConfigItem Id="2" Value="">
```

and in the opposite order of attributes, meaning like that:

```
[XmlElement(Type = typeof(ConfigItem)), XmlElement(ElementName = "Item")]
```

the xml looks like that:

```
<Item Id="2">
```

Any one can help me?

Comment: @IceN That question asks about ordering of the runtime objects marked with specific attributes, not ordering of the attributes in IL or decompiler.

Comment: May I ask why it's important to preserve the order of metadata attributes? It shouldn't make any difference in terms of execution or consumption of the component by others.

Comment: @Dor It sounds like you're relying on implementation details of XmlSerializer here when issuing it conflicting attributes like that, forcing it pick one or the other. Why not use a single attribute that is self-consistent?